# CoreData Save Error

Tags: ios, core-data

I am getting an NSValidationErrorObject when saving my managed object context.  I am trying to save a couple objects and they all get the same error (from the user info):

```
NSDetailedErrors = (
    Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
    Code=1680 "The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 1680.)"
    UserInfo=0x5d96fb0 {NSValidationErrorObject=<Alert: 0x5bb1fb0> (entity: Alert; id: 0x5bb0600 <x-coredata:///Alert/tBA1FD03B-5157-4523-AB34-A7C05869778F12> ;
        data: {
        ...
        identifier = "cap_024_0713_320117515151";
        ...}),
    NSValidationErrorKey=identifier,
    NSLocalizedDescription=The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (Cocoa error 1680.), 
    NSValidationErrorPredicate=SELF MATCHES "", 
    NSValidationErrorValue=cap_024_0713_320117515151}
```

The thing that is confusing me is that I can find no reason for that key to cause a validation error.  It is optional and as far as I know there is no validation enabled on it.  Is there some other place to check for validation to be set up? Could this error message be reporting the wrong field?

[image: identifier setup]

**Additional tests that i have now performed:**

- Saving after each update.  No change.
- Fresh store. No change.
- No warnings mentioned regarding reserved words.
- No manual validation whatsoever in the .m files.
- If I delete the "identifier" attribute, it works.
- If I add it back as "alertIdentifier" it does not work, but I used auto-migration so I'll try it again without migration.
- **If I delete the "identifier attribute" and add it again, making it look the same as before, it works!**

Comment: Do you have a fetch stored in the data model?

Comment: Thats a good thought.  No fetched properties stored in the model whatsoever and no fetch requests.

Comment: if you can chop it up into pieces, do parts of the mods, then call save.  you might get more insight into what's being changed that it's not liking

Comment: I have tried it with two and five entities.  I'll try it with one as well to see what happens.

Comment: Just a reminder, I guess you already have tried to rename (or remove) the sql lite store, and launch the app again for having it recreated, it's a quick test to do. The other place to look for validation, is in NSManagedObject, but it's specifically written by the programmer in validateFor<Insert,Update...> ecc. Also as pointed out by bshirley and techzen if I am not wrong, reserved keywords for CoreData should be pointed out by the compiler, look for some kind of warnings.

Comment: Thanks Leonardo.  I just double checked, and there is no manual validation in the .m files, and there are no compiler warnings.  I'm trying the fresh sqllite store and renaming identifier next.

Comment: A completely fresh store has the same issue.

Comment: I would suggest updating the question to reflect the test you've performed based on comments and answers.

Comment: Could you dump your managed object context's `updatedObjects` and `insertedObjects` properties just before the save? Are you sure you're assigning a string to the identifier property?

Comment: The data is dumped in the error above.  identifier = "cap_024_0713_320117515151"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the attribute name `identifier` could be problematic - try `myIdentifier` and see if it works

(i had a problem calling something `description` because of the meaning in Obj-C)

**Edited to reflect comments and results:**

Delete the attribute all together, test to see if another failure crops up, then add it back if no error is present.

*Deleting the "identifier" attribute and adding it again in Xcode fixed the issue. This was probably caused by an Xcode Core Data modeler bug.*

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.  Renaming it to test and using a fresh store brings about the exact same issue.  Its determined to do some kind of validation and I don't know why!

Comment: there are some validation methods you can implement, perhaps doing so and tracing through the debugger might provide some insight?  (wild guess)

Comment: the `SELF MATCHES ""` part makes you suspect it's not optional, and nil, delete the attribute all together, test to see if another failure crops up, then add it back if no error is present

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess it is a naming collision caused by using "identifier" as a property name. It's similar to the error that crops up when people use "description" as a property name.

To test, change it to something else and see if it works.

Comment: i seem to have been channeling @TechZen

Comment: I'm going to try this out.  Good idea.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.  Renaming it to test and using a fresh store brings about the exact same issue.  Its determined to do some kind of validation and I don't know why!